# How to use isOpen method in ngbtooltip for angular 13?

Tags: html, angular, ng-bootstrap, angular13

I want to check whether to tooltip is open or not in angular 13 with use of `isOpen()` method.

Example:

```
<li class="mt-menu-icon-wrapper" placement="right" [ngbTooltip]="tooltip" triggers="manual"(mouseenter)="showTooltip('settings')" (mouseleave)="hideTooltip('settings')" 
[closeDelay]="300" (isOpen)="isOpenFlag" ></li> 

<ng-template #tooltip>
Welcome to New Year Party
</ng-template>`
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

according to ngbtooltip doc https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/tooltip/api

`isOpen` is a method and not an input/output

if you want to set a boolean when tooltip is open or not you can play with the two output hidden and shown

> hidden : An event emitted when the tooltip closing animation has
> finished. Contains no payload.
>
> shown : An event emitted when the tooltip opening animation has
> finished. Contains no payload.

in your code it can look like

```
<li class="mt-menu-icon-wrapper" placement="right" [ngbTooltip]="tooltip" triggers="manual"(mouseenter)="showTooltip('settings')" (mouseleave)="hideTooltip('settings')" 
[closeDelay]="300" (shown)="tooltipDisplay(true)" (hidden)="tooltipDisplay(false)"></li>
```

in controller have a method

```
tooltipDisplay(isOpen:boolean) {
   this.isOpenFlag = isOpen;
}
```

Comment: To use a method, you need a reference to the object. So you should use a template reference variable:  (see the `#tootipTop`): `<button type="button" #tooltipTop="ngbTooltip"  class="btn btn-outline-secondary mr-2" placement="top" ngbTooltip="Tooltip on top">`. Then, You can use get with ViewChild or ViewChildren or in .html using simply {{tooltip.isOpen()}} -you can use also in a function-. See that to say Angular the the object is really a ngbTooltip you use `#tooltipTop="ngbTooltip"`. a [fool stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-hxihyp?file=src%2Fapp%2Ftooltip-basic.html)